# How to create a mailing list in Unix

Tags: email, shell-scripting

I have to write a shell script using a here document that will send a personalized greeting email to each student on a mailing list. I am using following script to sent mail to individual users:

```
$ cat > here.sh
mail $1 << endoftext
Dear $1
Welcome to the Unix Class
-$USER
endof text
```

I am new to Unix so am not able to create mailing list.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: ...although this sounds like homework.

Comment: @David it reeks of homework :-)

Comment: It smells like stack overflow homework, too...

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** Create an alias in your mail system's alias file (`/etc/aliases` or `/etc/mail/aliases` is usually the right spot), and use it do direct email to the addresses that should be on your list.  Manage by editing (and recompiling) the aliases list / database.
Refer to the man page for the aliases file and your MTA documentation for additional information.

**Method 2:** Install [some](http://www.ezmlm.org/) [mailing list](http://www.greatcircle.com/majordomo/) [software](http://www.emailman.com/unix/mailinglist.html).
Manage in accordance with the documentation provided.

Note that you will need root access in order to implement either of these solutions, however implementing (2) typically allows non-root users to be mailing list managers, and is a much preferred solution.